# ASP.Net Ajax toolkit client side code and javascript questions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, function, toolkit

I am trying to understand the sample client side code for using ASP.Net Ajax calendar control. Here is the sample code from asp.net web site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
<head runat="server">  
    <title>Untitled Page</title>  
    <style type="text/css">  
    </style>  
    <link href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/extended/Calendar/Calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/Start.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/extended/ExtendedControls.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        Sys.debug = true;  
        Sys.require(Sys.components.calendar, function() {  
            $("#bdate").calendar({});  
        });  
    </script>  
</head>  
<body>  

    <div style="width:1px;height:500px"></div>  
    <input type="text" id="bdate" />  


</body>  
</html>
```

According to some documents, the following lines load a javascript file `Sys.require())`.

`$("#bdate")` uses jQuery to find an object with id "bdate". I don't understand the rest, especially the

1. `.calendar({}),` especially the `({}),`
2. `function()`

Any help or hints are appreciated!!!!

```
Sys.require(Sys.components.calendar, function() {  
    $("#bdate").calendar({});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it:

This part of the line makes sure the calendar scripts/root objects are ready

```
Sys.require(Sys.components.calendar
```

And when they are ready, it invokes the anonymous function, which finds the item with ID **bdate**, (the textbox in the html), and attaches calendar display functionality to it with the **calendar** method.  (probably pops up a calendar when the textbox control gets focus).  The **calendar** method was registered by the **Sys.components.calendar** object and is basically an extension method that can be called on textbox objects that are returned by jquery selector invocations. (e.g. $("#xyz"), where #xyz denotes an element with id 'xyz' somewhere in your html)

```
function() {  
    $("#bdate").calendar({});  
}
```

This is an anonymous function that can be passed as a paramter as well.  So it is basically the second parameter to the **require** call (kind of like a function pointer in C/C+++, but declared inline).  This method is called when the calendar objects/scripts have all been loaded and initialized.

finally, the `{}` part means it is passing an empty javascript object with no properties to the calendar creation method.  The method most likely takes a number of optional parameters in the form of a javascript object with optional properties, none of which are used here.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

1.is just calling the default 'calendar' creation function, imagine it as a constructor. The {} is a method of defining a JSON string which would usually be where you add your configuration options. E.G.

```
calender({
        someOption: true,
        someOtherOption: false,
        height: 120px
    });
```

2.Is a way to pass a function as an object in Javascript, or an anonomous function. All it's saying is that for the second parameter of 'require' use the function. This is often called a callback function, as depending on the method the function is passed into it can be executed when the originating method completes/calls back.

In this context, the function defined is a jQuery call to create a calendar control, so in basic terms you could imagine it saying something like this:

Require(The component) and then once we have that component, call the function '$("#bdate").calendar({});'

As a further explanation the function $("#bdate").calendar({}); will be creating a calendar control on the element with an ID of bddate.